# Dojo GridX with 100% width and adaptable column widths?

Tags: css, dojo, dojo.gridx

I just condider using GridX as grid component in my application. I try to find out how to configure some things.

At first I want to hava grid that would have full width of viewport, that would have a few columns with fixed width, but all others would adapt to the viewport.

In 'normal' table I set width to 100% to the table, width to fixed columns, and min-width to auto-resize columns. But here I can't find an example.

There is a demo test_grid_columnwidth.html, but it doesn't have the features I want. The 'Grid of autoWidth' is wider that viewport at start.

After changing the width attribute of .gridx and .gridxBody, the grid is adapted to viewport, but the columns are not adapted and some of them dissapear.

When I follow https://github.com/oria/gridx/wiki/Introduction-to-Gridx and set `.gridx {width:100%;}`, the grid container is adapted to viewport, there is scroll, but the columns are neither shrinked nor expanded.

OK, I think my requirement is quite basic. So how to do that with GridX? Am I missing something?